# Import js from a typescript dependency in create-react-app?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

In https://github.com/DavidSouther/monots I have a straightforward multi-project Typescript configuration.

common/ has library utilities, and gets compiled from src/ to lib/. The package.json is (I believe) set up to expose the .js and .d.ts files from lib/ to consumers, and the .js is in commonjs.

app/ has a create-react-app project, which imports from `common/`. When starting, it fails to build with

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'common' in '/Users/dsouther/devel/monots/app/src'
```

What configuration do I need in `common/` for create-react-app to be able to pack these files correctly?